# Ruby on Rails Saving in two tables from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, save

I have two models Hotel and Address.
Relationships are:

```
class Hotel
  belongs_to :user
  has_one    :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

and

```
class Address
  belongs_to :hotel
```

And I need to save in **hotels** table and in **addresses** table from one form.

The input form is simple:

```
<%= form_for(@hotel) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  ......other hotel fields......

  <%= f.fields_for :address do |o| %>
    <%= o.text_field :country %>
    ......other address fields......

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hotels controller:

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
  end

  def create
    @hotel = current_user.hotels.build(hotel_params)
    address = @hotel.address.build
    if @hotel.save      
      flash[:success] = "Hotel created!"
      redirect_to @hotel
    else
      render 'new'      
    end    
  end
```

But this code doesn't work.

**ADD 1**
Hotel_params:

```
  private
    def hotel_params
      params.require(:hotel).permit(:title, :stars, :room, :price)
    end
```

**ADD 2**

The main problem is I don't know how to render form properly. This ^^^ form doesn't even include adress fields (country, city etc.). But if in the line

```
<%= f.fields_for :address do |o| %>
```

I change :address to :hotel, I get address fields in the form, but of course nothing saves in :address table in this case.  I don't understand the principle of saving in 2 tables from 1 form, I'm VERY sorry, I'm new to Rails...

Comment: Can you provide your `hotel_params` method as well, please.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what is the output of submitting this form?

Comment: @Vapire, of course, added hotel_params.

Comment: @khaled_gomaa, of course, I decribed this form in ADD2.

Comment: Your current way of having that `form` is correct.Don't mess with it.I guess the culprits here is your `new` and `create` methods.Can you just try my answer and say it works or not.

Comment: And also the main thing is your `hotel_params` doesn't have your address fields. I will update my answer.Please tell me your address fields.

Comment: @Pavan, :country, :state, :city and :street.

Comment: What about the foreign key? How would I set addressess :hotel_id = to hotels :id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using **`wrong method`** for appending your child with the parent.And also it is **`has_one relation`**,so you should use **`build_model`** not **`model.build`**.Your `new` and `create` methods should be like this

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
    @hotel.build_address #here
  end

  def create
    @hotel = current_user.hotels.build(hotel_params)

    if @hotel.save      
      flash[:success] = "Hotel created!"
      redirect_to @hotel
    else
      render 'new'      
    end    
  end
```

**Update**

Your `hotel_params` method should look like this

```
def hotel_params
   params.require(:hotel).permit(:title, :stars, :room, :price,address_attributes: [:country,:state,:city,:street])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention! With the line    address = @hotel.address.build    in "def new" I get an error at this line: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass  when try to access add page..

Comment: Still undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: @AlMacks I have updated my answer.Now it should work.

Comment: What about the foreign key? How would I set addressess :hotel_id = hotels :id?

Answer (score 2):

You should not build address again

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
  end

  def create
    @hotel = current_user.hotels.build(hotel_params)
    # address = @hotel.address.build 
    # the previous line should not be used
    if @hotel.save      
      flash[:success] = "Hotel created!"
      redirect_to @hotel
    else
      render 'new'      
    end    
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, khaled_gomaa!

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line here is you need to use the `f.fields_for` method correctly.

--

**Controller**

There are several things you need to do to get the method to work. Firstly, you need to build the associated object, then you need to be able to pass the data in the right way to your model:

```
#app/models/hotel.rb
Class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :address
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

#app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb
Class HotelsController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @hotel = Hotel.new
       @hotel.build_address #-> build_singular for singular assoc. plural.build for plural
    end

    def create
        @hotel = Hotel.new(hotel_params)
        @hotel.save
    end

    private

    def hotel_params
        params.require(:hotel).permit(:title, :stars, :room, :price, address_attributes: [:each, :address, :attribute])
    end
end
```

This should work for you.

--

**Form**

Some tips for your form - if you're loading the form & not seeing the `f.fields_for` block showing, it basically means you've not set your `ActiveRecord Model` correctly (in the `new` action)

What I've written above (which is very similar to that written by `Pavan`) should get it working for you

Comment: @Richard i'm not able to see the **f.fields_for** can you help me with this?

Comment: Are you using `<%= f.fields_for ...`?

Comment: What do I do about foreign keys?