# Error in Form when saving to 2 Tables in Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, save

I saw a similar answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746906/ruby-on-rails-saving-in-two-tables-from-one-form/43242398) which got me this far. But now I am facing an error in Form. The solution I am looking for is basically saving to two tables in Ruby Rails where saving the Property with address in first table also saves 2 images in Pictures' second table.

Migration1:

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.string :address

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Migration2:

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string :image1
      t.string :image2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Property Model:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pictures
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
end
```

Picture Model:

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :property
end
```

PropertiesController:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_property

  def new
    @property = Property.new
  end

  def create
    @property = properties.build(property_params)
    if @property.save
      flash[:success] = "Property was successfully created"
      redirect_to property_path(@property)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def property_params
      params.require(:property).permit(:address, picture_attributes: [:image1, :image2])
    end
end
```

The FORM which I don't know is done as below:

```
<%= form_for(@property) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :address %>
<%= f.text_field :address %>

<%= f.label :image1 %>
<%= f.text_field :image1 %>

<%= f.label :image2 %>
<%= f.text_field :image2 %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Error Picture:

[Error on new.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gtEN.png)

Comment: Sometimes, a form object is a good alternative to complicated nested forms that model complicated nested relationships. Just search "ruby on rails form object" for more info...

Comment: Thanks for the tip Brad, will read up on this definitely!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `fields_for` method to have a form for pictures inside the property form:

```
# inside the property form_for
<%= f.fields_for @property.pictures.build do |p| %>
  <%= p.file_field :image1 %>
  <%= p.file_field :image2 %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Amr! will certainly try this out tomorrow and will report back.!

Comment: One last thing, in your `property_params` it's `pictures_attributes` not `picture_attributes`. Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, i was playing around with that in singular/plural but will stick to plural now!

Comment: ok..i tried this in form: `<%= form_for(@property) do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :address %>
 <%= f.text_field :address %>

  <%= f.fields_for @property.pictures.build do |p| %>
    <%= p.file_field :image1 %>
    <%= p.file_field :image2 %> 
  <% end %> 


 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>` but it is giving me error >> unknown attribute 'property_id' for Picture (around line #5)

Comment: Rails expects a foreign key field `property_id` in your pictures table for the association to work. Create a migration and add this field and it should work.

Comment: I added a migration 'rails g migration add_property_id_to_pictures property_id:integer' then 'rails db:migrate' - Still getting error on controller params being in correct. Am i missing anything in both model files in terms of foreign key clause? Sorry I am still learning rails so not used to this. However I am still searching and reading up on this so will keep trying..!

Comment: no, it's totally okay these things help you learn for sure. could you post the error you're getting now

Comment: Sorry I mean form works now, that is sorted but when I submit the fields, get an error: >> `NameError in PropertiesController#create
undefined local variable or method `properties' for #<PropertiesController:0x9fba0c0>
Extracted source (around line #8):
  def create
    @property = properties.build(property_params)
    if @property.save
      flash[:success] = "Property was successfully created"
      redirect_to property_path(@property)`

Comment: `app/controllers/properties_controller.rb:8:in `create'
Request
Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"FkMU6CuAIf25LeaHR+eluPj7v4Tury+EuLLjR6zksZs5LFfqf/It1R5m5Z4tGm96uN05lmj9P1n0OSP1rnL7BQ==",
 "property"=>{"address"=>"add1", "picture"=>{"image1"=>"url1", "image2"=>"url2"}},
 "commit"=>"Create Property"}`

Comment: Form is like this now: `<%= form_for(@property) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :address %>
<%= f.text_field :address %></br>

<%= f.fields_for @property.pictures.build do |p| %>
  <%= p.text_field :image1 %></br>
  <%= p.text_field :image2 %></br>
<% end %> 


<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>`

Comment: Controller like this now: `class PropertiesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @property = Property.new
  end

  def create
    @property = properties.build(property_params)
    if @property.save
      flash[:success] = "Property was successfully created"
      redirect_to property_path(@property)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def property_params
      params.require(:property).permit(:address, pictures_attributes: [:image1, :image2])
    end
end`

Comment: Models like this now: `class Property < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :pictures
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
end

class Picture < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :property
end`

Comment: in your properties_controller's `create` action change the first line to this: `@property = Property.build(property_params)`

Comment: changed to `@property = Property.build(property_params)` but error is now different. It says build method or class not found for controller. I think I will have to rewrite this again. But thanks for all your help!!