# In Rails 5.1, how do I use one form to update two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to get one form to update two tables in Ruby on Rails. I have done a fairly exhaustive search on here and I'm finding the guides a little confusing. The closest answer I have found is this:

[Ruby on Rails Saving in two tables from one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746906/ruby-on-rails-saving-in-two-tables-from-one-form)

I have mostly copied this answer but I still can't get it to work. Here are the relevant bits of code:

Models - I have two models, supplier and account. Each supplier should have one account.

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :account
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supplier
end
```

Form - not sure if this is entirely correct

```
<h2>Please enter a supplier</h2>
  <%= form_for(@supplier) do |form| %>

<p>
  <%= form.label :name %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
</p>

<p>
 <%= form.fields_for :account do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :account_number %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :account_number %>
</p>

<p>
 <%= form.submit %>
</p>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And finally, the `SuppliersController`

```
class SuppliersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @suppliers = Supplier.all
  end

  def new
    @supplier = Supplier.new
    @supplier = build_account
  end

  def create
    @supplier = suppliers.build(supplier_params)

    if @supplier.save
      redirect_to suppliers_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private

  def supplier_params
    params.require(:supplier).permit(:name, account_attributes: 
                                             [:account_number])
  end

end
```

I am getting an undefined method error on the second line of the new action of the `SuppliersController` and I don't know why.

Debugging printout for create action in `SupplierController`:

Started POST "/suppliers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-03 08:25:25 -0600
Processing by SuppliersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KEqvPgjrYmuBux3qWCQJLAkSLQ4z1ns4HsK2P9sWlhVegpjhik/JoWT3vlL/kP42XpU8adllOaqSA16izYJ0SA==", "supplier"=>{"name"=>"", "account_attributes"=>{"account_number"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Create Supplier"}

(0.1ms)  begin transaction

SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "suppliers" ("created_at", "updated_at", "name") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2017-11-03 14:25:25.388933"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-03 14:25:25.388933"], ["name", "Bob"]]

(0.6ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction

Supplier Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "suppliers".* FROM "suppliers" WHERE "suppliers"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "accounts" ("created_at", "updated_at", "account_number", "supplier_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2017-11-03 14:25:25.424367"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-03 14:25:25.424367"], ["account_number", "456456456"], ["supplier_id", 6]]

(0.6ms)  commit transaction

Supplier: #Supplier id: 6, created_at: "2017-11-03 14:25:25", updated_at: "2017-11-03 14:25:25", name: "Bob"

Account: #Account id: 1, created_at: "2017-11-03 14:25:25", updated_at: "2017-11-03 14:25:25", account_number: "456456456", supplier_id: 6

(0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/suppliers
Completed 302 Found in 51ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)

Comment: I assume it's undefined function "build_account" ? Do you have that function ?

Comment: The guides say that the build_association method is added when adding the has_one association to the Supplier Model. This is why I'm confused because the method should be there

Comment: When you look at the log, what are the parameters showing as? The line will contain `INFO -- :   Parameters:` soon after the Started POST line. It is likely that you need to permit the parameters for the :account.

Comment: @Phil I should have been more clear, this is failing when the new method is called. Assuming I understand how the logger works, there is not a POST request at this point as it is a GET request. The log just shows the GET request, all parameters being nil upon the initialization of `@supplier` and then an undefined method `build_account` along with a "Completed 500 Internal Service Error" When you say log, you mean what gets printed in the in command line? (I've honestly never used this)

Comment: Sorry, missed that wasn't the problem. Should have guessed by looking at your code more closely. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `build_account` is a method on a supplier object. As you have your code, it is currently trying to run build_account as if it was a method on the SuppliersController

So, you should try updating your controller method for new to:

```
def new
  @supplier = Supplier.new
  @account = @supplier.build_account
end
```

This calls the `build_account` against the supplier object you have just instantiated, returning the result as an instantiated account object, associated with the supplier instance it belongs to.

The build_account method is generated through the association you have defined in your supplier model, where you say `has_one :account`. The docs here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference describe all the methods that are created in this way.

**EDIT**

Following up on the question about the create action, the controller should be updated. In the comments we have debugged the models and they appear to work as we would hope, so once updated the controller should work as:

```
def create
  # Created a Supplier, but not yet persisted.
  @supplier = Supplier.new(supplier_params)

  # Persists the supplier, giving him an id, which can then be used
  # through implicit autosave functionality to take the nested params
  # to build the associated account. All of these operations are wrapped
  # in a single DB transaction, ensuring nothing is left dangling if
  # there is a validation failure
  if @supplier.save
    redirect_to suppliers_path
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Based on the association autosave functionality, new associated records (account) should be automatically created based on the nested parameters being passed from the form, at the point the supplier is saved, without having to add any additional code to explicitly handle this. More autosave options are documented here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

Comment: thank you for explaining where `build_account` was running - huge help to clarifying how things work. I have one more issue in the `create` action in the `SuppliersController`. It fails on the first line. I have since changed the code to `@suppliers = Supplier.new(supplier_params)` however, that does not persist anything to the tables. How do I get it to do so?

Comment: Try changing the save line to: `if @supplier.save!` just to debug (you'll want to change it back later. If there is a problem, save! will raise an exception.

Comment: okay did that and the error thrown is ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in SuppliersController#create / Validation failed: Account supplier must exist. I haven't a clue how to fix this or even where to start looking to find the answer. Best guess is the account parameters aren't being built into my `@supplier` object

Comment: hmm... two things: first see if you can do `@supplier = Supplier.create(name: 'Bob')` - this should work fine. If so, then try `acc = @supplier.build_account(account_number: 123)`. That will check the associations are in place...

Comment: 2nd: I'm wondering if your supplier_params is correctly specified. Try this instead: `params.require(:supplier).permit(:name, account_attributes: 
                                             {:account_number})`

Comment: 1st change works. 'Bob' is persisted to the database. Building the account to supplier did not work. I get the following error: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in SuppliersController#create
Validation failed: Account supplier must exist

The parameter print out is as follows: Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"8vZ9Tagl1HUFBawT93+Z98lwTHpLlNjc0bYD7iD1CTyEPkqSKoF/v+BJD6tQy27tnvddHaEnmk5dd+tzNmHrYQ==",
 "supplier"=>{"name"=>"", "account_attributes"=>{"account_number"=>""}},
 "commit"=>"Create Supplier"}

Comment: 2nd: The change to `supplier_params` fails with a syntax error. `account_attributes:` takes an array. I found this in the form helper guide.

Comment: Further, when I use `logger.debug acc.inspect` to look at the `acc = @supplier.build_account(account_number: "456456456")` line, it shows #<Account id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, account_number: "45645645646", supplier_id: nil>

I thought rails was supposed to fill the rest out automatically. Could the 'nil's be what's stopping it from saving?

Comment: The id, created_at, updated_at are not filled until the item is saved. The supplier_id should be filled in automatically through the build_account. I'm leading you through the debug process here, so bear with me... So, next step coming up...

Comment: Replace the @supplier.build_account line with: `acc = Account.create(account_number: "456456456", supplier_id: @supplier.id)` and also do a `logger.debug "Supplier: #{@supplier.inspect}\nAccount: #{acc.inspect}" ` just so we can see what is going in. Hopefully this will give the info that is needed to tell why the association build is not working.

Comment: sorry I'll slow down and thanks for walking me through this in a way where I can actually internalize it. The results are edited into my original post due to length.

Comment: So that looks to me like the account was created correctly. I don't see why, based on that, you can't get the build_account to work. If you take out that last Account.create line and replace it with `acc = @supplier.create_account(account_number: "456456456")` it should work. Adding a line `logger.debug acc.errors.inspect` should show any hidden errors.

Comment: Okay that new `@supplier.create_account` line worked. I don't think it threw any errors but here is the section in the log that pertains to the `logger.debug' line:

#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe1933fc330 @base=#<Account id: 9, created_at: "2017-11-03 15:09:00", updated_at: "2017-11-03 15:09:00", account_number: "345ABC", supplier_id: 14>, @messages={}, @details={}>

Comment: The account was created OK, since it has an ID. That is good. So, we have tested that at the model level everything is operating as it should. So, stepping back up to the 'create' action in the controller, take a look at the edit I'm about to make in the main answer.

Comment: I'm now getting a missing method error on suppliers in that new line you provided `@supplier = suppliers.new(supplier_params)` From reading the association guides, I don't think a suppliers method is created on has_one associations.

Comment: okay so now it saves the supplier part of the record but it is not saving anything into the Account table. In the log it is saying "Unpermitted parameter :account and then it shows everything else being saved correctly. After a little googling I'm pretty sure it has something to do with strong parameters and which ones I've whitelisted. I'm confused though because from all the examples I could find, it looks like I've set up my supplier_params method correctly. What should I do now?

Comment: nvm my comment above, I figured it out. I made the mistake of changing my fields_for line in my form. I changed it to `@account` when it should have been `:account`. As soon as I changed it back, it started working and the correct records were being saved in the correct tables. Thank you very much for walking me through all of this. I really appreciate it. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score -1):

from the guides, this section

[4.1.1 Methods Added by belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to)

each **instance** of the Book model will have these methods:

So as my friend points below, I assume

```
@supplier = Supplier.build_account // wrong
@account = @supplier.build_account
```

would be correct

Comment: You're looking in correct direction. However, the code, as shown, is wrong. What do you think `Supplier.build_account` would return, if there was such method (hint: it's not on `Supplier`)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it would return a new instance of the associated class but I can't call it on `Supplier`. I think I figured it out - I have to call it on `@supplier` so I can build the associated object's (`@account`) parameters into `@supplier`. Is this correct both in what I need to do and how I explained it?

Comment: @jive14: yes, you got it. `@account = @supplier.build_account`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Any ideas on how to get my create action in the `SupplierController` working. I can't get the record submitted in the form to save to the database

Comment: @jive14: I have many ideas on how to write working code, but I have no idea why is _your_ code not working.