# Rails Creating 2 Identical Models with one form

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, simple-form

I am working on a project where users submit one form and it is saved into a waterusage model. Then they need to make goals in a goals model. The goals model has identical attributes to the waterusage model so when the waterusage object is created I need a goals object created at the same time. Then when the user goes back to set goals they will be given a subset of the attributes which they can edit and compare to their initial results.

Here are the models:

```
    class Waterusage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  before_validation :calculate_totals

  def calculate_totals
    self.home_usage = get_home_usage
    self.outdoor_usage = get_outdoor_usage
    self.vehicle_usage = get_vehicle_usage
    self.power_usage = get_power_usage
    self.indirect_source_usage = get_indirect_source_usage
    self.household_total = get_household_total
    self.individual_total = get_individual_total
  end

  def get_household_total
    home_usage + outdoor_usage + vehicle_usage + power_usage + indirect_source_usage
  end

  def get_individual_total
    household_total / household_size
  end

  def get_home_usage
    shower_total + bath_total + bathroom_sink_total + toilet_total + 
    kitchen_total + dishwashing_total + laundry_total + greywater
  end

  def get_outdoor_usage
    lawn_total + swimming_total
  end

  def get_vehicle_usage
    (0.735 * miles) + carwash_total
  end

  def get_power_usage
    statewater * percent_statewater / 100
  end

  def get_indirect_source_usage
    (household_size*(shopping + paper_recycling + plastic_recycling + can_recycling + textile_recycling + diet)) + (200 * pet_cost / 30)
  end

  ... (Insert many sub calculations here of attributes in the waterusages schema)
end
```

**The goals model is identical.**

In the goals controller it needs to create a new instance using the waterusages instance associated with the same current_user.

The goals controller needs to edit it's attributes independently from waterusages.

How do I set goals.new equal to waterusage.new ? In one of the controllers, models?

Comment: Please be specific with your problem. While you may have access to your code and you know the problem, just by reading this paragraph it's difficult to understand what you're asking and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: See if answer here can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746906/ruby-on-rails-saving-in-two-tables-from-one-form?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I have added some code from the models to help. The models are identical, it's just that the second controller needs to create an instance using data from the first model. See above for additional clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In your `goals_controller.rb`, you can do :
`waterusage_params = waterusage.attributes.except('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at') # assuming that you have an instance of Waterusage
goal = Goal.create(waterusage_params)`